# Task Extension to Cater App Wide Service Calls

Tags: c#, generics, xamarin, xamarin.forms, async-await

I am working in xamarin and trying to consume all services using one method. For that I wrote a TaskExtension. So that from every page in the app I can call that extension method. This is to disable the buttons, show loading screen, response handling and to cater exception handling from one point. I am attaching my code below. Need your expert opinions on this solution

**Here is my Extension Class**

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static async Task<ResultViewModel<U>> ExecuteAsyncOperation<U>(this Task<HttpResponseMessage> operation, object sender = null)
    {
        ResultViewModel<U> resultModel = new ResultViewModel<U>();
        Button button = BeforeAsyncCall(sender);
        try
        {
            await BackgroundOperation(operation, resultModel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            resultModel.Status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            resultModel.Errors = new List<string>() { "Some error occurred. Please try again." };
        }
        finally
        {
            AfterAsyncCall(button);

        }
        return resultModel;
    }
    static async Task BackgroundOperation<U>(Task<HttpResponseMessage> operation, ResultViewModel<U> resultModel)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage RawResult = await operation;
        var Response = await RawResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        resultModel.Status = RawResult.StatusCode;
        if (RawResult.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseObj = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<U>(Response));
            resultModel.Result = responseObj;
        }
        else
        {
            var responseErrorObj = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorModel>(Response));
            resultModel.Errors = new List<string>();
            foreach (var modelState in responseErrorObj.ModelState)
            {
                foreach (var error in modelState.Value)
                {
                    resultModel.Errors.Add(error.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static Button BeforeAsyncCall(object sender)
    {
        Button button = null;
        if (sender != null)
            button = (Button)sender;
        if (button != null)
            button.IsEnabled = false;
        UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Loading", MaskType.Black);
        return button;
    }
    static void AfterAsyncCall(Button button)
    {
        UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
        if (button != null)
            button.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

**Here is the Call to my Extension Method**

```
ResultViewModel<TokenModel> response = await new Service(Settings.BaseUrl).Login(loginModel).ExecuteAsyncOperation<TokenModel>(sender);
```

**ResultViewModel**

```
public class ResultViewModel<T> 
    {
        public HttpStatusCode Status { get; set; }
        public T Result { get; set; }
        public List<string> Errors { get; set; }
    }
```

**Async Method**

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Login(LoginViewModel loginModel)
        {
            try
            {

                var dataList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                dataList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"));
                dataList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", loginModel.Email));
                dataList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", loginModel.Password));
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
                {
                    RequestUri = new Uri(this.BaseUrl + "token"),
                    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                    Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dataList)
                };
                var authenticateResponse = await Client.SendAsync(request);
                return authenticateResponse;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

My questions is

1) Is this a good approach?

2) Can we improve it in terms of performance?

3) Am I using Async correctly?

Comment: @Muhmmad Omer Aslam have a look please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is this a good approach?

There is nothing wrong with this approach.

> 2) Can we improve it in terms of performance?

There shouldn't be any performance issues with using an extension method, but you can measure to be 100% certain. You are creating a boxing and unboxing situation with the `object` to `button` casting. Could you just use `Button`. Use `ViewElement` if you want to support multiple element types. Also, There are penalties for using `async await`, but they are minimal and necessary to not block the UI. You can increase performance by removing the need to recapture the context by adding `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to your tasks, but in your case you need context to re-enable the button. The use of `dynamic` seems unnecessary and does have some overhead.

> 3) Am I using Async correctly?

You don't have to `await` a `Task` if the method just returns a `Task`. You can `await` it from the calling method. This will reduce overhead on the compiler, and may increase performance. I haven't tested this out before though.

**Extension**

```
public static async Task<ResultViewModel<T>> ExecuteAsyncOperation<T>(this Task<HttpResponseMessage> operation, Button button)
{
    ResultViewModel<T> resultModel = new ResultViewModel<T>();
    try
    {
        if (button != null)
            button.IsEnabled = false;
        HttpResponseMessage RawResult = await operation;
        string Response = await RawResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        resultModel.Status = RawResult.StatusCode;

        if (RawResult.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var responseObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(Response);
            resultModel.Result = responseObj;
        }
        else
        {
            //create an error model instead of using dynamic I am guessing modelstate here
            List<ModelState> responseObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ModelState>>(Response);
            resultModel.Errors = new List<string>();
            foreach (ModelState modelState in responseObj)
            {
                foreach (var error in modelState.Errors)
                {
                    resultModel.Errors.Add(error.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        resultModel.Status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        resultModel.Errors = new List<string>() { "Some error occurred. Please try again." };
    }
    finally
    {
        if (button != null)
            button.IsEnabled = true;
    }
    return resultModel;
}
```

**Calling**

```
var button = sender as Button; 
if (button != null)
{
    ResultViewModel<TokenModel> response = await new Service(Settings.BaseUrl).Login(loginModel).ExecuteAsyncOperation<TokenModel>(sender);
}
```

**Request**

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> Login(LoginViewModel loginModel)
{
    var dataList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    dataList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"));
    dataList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", loginModel.Email));
    dataList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", loginModel.Password));
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri(this.BaseUrl + "token"),
        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
        Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dataList)
    };
    return Client.SendAsync(request);
}
```

Comment: I have used dynamic so that later on if I need to return something other than HttpResponseMessage  I can. I will use switch statement in that case. Secondly, I need to cast button before calling every method why not unbox it at one place?. Lastly, I have read that async and await should be used all the way. Even in the Api Controllers. What's your take on that?

Comment: `var responseErrorObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorModel>(Response);`. Already used model here forgot to update the code.

Comment: `HttpResponseMessage RawResult = await operation;`. Can't do this because it gives compile time error. _cannot implicitly convert T to HttpResponseMessage_

Comment: You have said it not a bad approach. Can you please refer some better approach. Like a link to some blog?

Comment: You are boxing and unboxing twice, once with the event when you are implicitly casting to `button` and again when you call your method and unbox again. You will have to unbox somewhere for your event trigger. You are getting the _cannot implicitly convert T to HttpResponseMessage_ error because I changed the method signature to use `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` instead of `Task<T>` to avoid the use of `dynamic`. I only pointed out the overhead and gave solutions, if they don't work for your situation then you can always make compromises.

Comment: I said it is not a bad approach and in this is perfectly acceptable. You are creating code that is reusable and has a single purpose. You are using `async await` properly. I was just pointing out that for example when you call `ExecuteAsyncOperation<TokenModel>(sender)` you can add `ConfigureAwait(false)` to improve performance a bit if you have code that executes after this call that does not need to reference anything in the UI. `ConfigureAwait` basically says when I come back from awaiting this task, do I need to wait to run on the calling thread so I can manage something in that context.

Comment: One last thing how to show loader using this approach?. I am not able to use Navigation Property in this extension class.

Comment: You would retrieve any UI elements outside of the extension method and pass them in as a param just as you have done with the button.